# Overloading the prefix and postfix increment operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
const Rational & Rational::operator++()          //Prefix form
{
    numer += denom;
    return *this;
}

Rational Rational::operator++(int)                  //Postfix form
{
    Rational tmp = *this;
    numer += denom;
    return tmp;
}
```

The code above relates to the implementation of a `Rational` number class. While the class has a number of operations which have been omitted for brevity, its most important components are two private integer members `numer` and `denom`, which denote the numerator and denominator, respectively.

The intent of this code is to overload the prefix and postfix increment operators (`++`) such that they can be used on `Rational` types, with the net overall effect being that the rational number represented by a `Rational` object is incremented by 1 when each of the operators are used on it. Here is what I don't understand:

Firstly, the return type for the first method is a constant reference, yet a dereferenced `this` object shows up in the `return` statement (`*this`), does that not mean that an object instead of a reference is actually returned?

Secondly, in the book "Data Structures and Problem Solving Using C++", where this code comes from, it is mentioned that an anonymous `int` argument is used to differentiate the type signatures of the prefix and postfix forms. What confuses me is that the return types are also different, why?

Lastly, and most importantly, how can I tell from just looking at the code how the compiler (or runtime, please clarify) would determine which method applies to the prefix form and which to the postfix equivalent?

Comment: Minor point: the postfix version should probably be `Rational tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp;`. That way you don't have to duplicate the code that does the increment; if you need to change how the increment is done later, it's best to only have that code in one place.

Comment: For the last part: `++object;` -> prefix; `obj++;` -> suffix. Furthermore usually you'd return a reference to non-const. Btw: dereferencing a pointer yields a reference to the type pointed to. E.g. this compiles without an error `double x = 0; double* p = &x; double& ref = *p;`

Comment: Your compiler will have no trouble, whatsoever, telling the difference between `++r`, the prefix form, and `r++`, the postfix form. C++ compilers are very good at this sort of a thing. P.S. one question per Stackoverflow question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Edit

> This was plain wrong as pointed out in the comments by @PeteBecker. You can't make the method `const` because then it couldn't update the value. My preference would be to return a non-`const` reference since the function is not `const`, but there are reasons to consider a `const` reference as mentioned in the comments.

> > The first signature should not be `const` unless you are going to declare the method const as well. Rational& operator++();

The return statement is going to be exactly the same whether you are returning an object or a reference -- both instances will look like you are returning an object. What actually gets returned depends on the method signature and in this case it is a reference.

The return type for the first method can be a reference to the object because you are incrementing the object first before returning it, i.e. pre-increment.

The return type for the second method has to an object because you need to return the original value before it is incremented, i.e. post-increment.

The syntax is different for each method:

```
++i; // pre-incrmeent - calls first method
i++; // post-increment - calls second method
```

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for more examples.

Comment: "*See cppreference for more examples*" - you linked to the general "operator overloading" page. Also see the ["Increment/decrement operators"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) page.

Comment: Re: "should not be const unless ..." -- you can't declare the increment operator to be a `const` member function; if you did it couldn't increment the object. There's nothing inherently wrong with returning a `const` reference from a non-const member function; I'd seriously consider doing exactly that, because the only use for returning a non-const reference is writing unreadable or pointless code. `++r = 3;`?

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree, you can't make it `const` -- I wasn't thinking straight.  I think there are some reasonable uses for returning non-`const` though. Consider a method that takes and returns a non-`const` reference as part of argument chaining -- I might write something like `return ++i` at the end of the method, which seems like a natural way to increment and return a reference to the object. It is certainly not pointless. See [Argument Chaining](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-method-chaining-in-c-3ec9f255972a) as an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. That is more precise. Thank you.